# Any ideas why this won't print?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

This is the main class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
class BinarySearchTree {
private Node root;

public void main()
{
    int Value = 0;
    while(Value!= -1)
    {
        Value = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a value"));
        insert(root, Value); 
    }
    print();
}

public void insert(Comparable x) 
{
    root = insert(root, x);
}

public boolean find(Comparable x) 
{
    return find(root,x);
}

public void print() 
{
    print(root);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
boolean find(Node tree, Comparable x) 
{
    if (tree == null)
        return false;

    if (x.compareTo(tree.data) == 0) 
        return true;

    if (x.compareTo(tree.data) < 0)
        return find(tree.left, x);
    else
        return find(tree.right, x);
}

void print(Node tree) 
{
    if (tree != null) 
    {
        print(tree.left);
        System.out.println(tree.data);
        print(tree.right);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Node insert(Node tree, Comparable x) 
{
    if (tree == null) 
    {
        return new Node(x);
    }

    if (x.compareTo(tree.data) < 0) 
    {
        tree.left = insert(tree.left, x);
        return tree;
    } 
    else 
    {
        tree.right = insert(tree.right, x);
        return tree;
    }
}
```

}

Node class:

```
public class Node {
    public Comparable data;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;

    Node(Comparable newdata) {
        data = newdata;
    }
}
```

I try to print out the results when I call "print();" in the void main class, after inserting all the values in the tree but it does not print anything. When I individually call each method, they work, but not when I try to call them from the main class. Any reasons why this is happening? Much thanks

Comment: Vote to close: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: `public void main()` .. giving no errors?

Comment: That is correct. And where would I find a debugger to use?

Comment: @vidit was hinting; should be `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: @anorton: I don't think we're there yet :)

Comment: I get the error: "non static variable cannot be referenced from a static context" for the root deceleration.

Comment: @user1136610:  Whenever you call methods that belong to the object, you have to create a new instance of that object, then call the methods from that instance.

Answer (score 4):

It is because you dont have a main method. Change the signature of your main method to:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

and re run it.